# Writing Javascript Code to support Multi-browsers

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, xrm

I am new to CRM 2011 Javascript,Can anyone please suggest me in writing the below lines in CRM 2011 Javascript to support multi browsers please.

In IE it is working fine but not in other browsers

```
crmForm.new_schemaname.DataValue = crmForm.all.schemaname.DataValue;
```

I tried to write like this

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_schemaname").getValue() = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("schemaname").getValue();
```

Throwing error saying **Can't assign to a function result**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the setValue function

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_weightedpercentage").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("CFPoppStage").getValue());`
```

You'll probably also want to check for null values before blindly assigning and reading values...

Comment: To complement @Daryl information, check for example this [article](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/crm-2011-javascript-xrm-page-basics/) talk about the new object model.